# SQL Server collation resolve

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

```
select 'GRANT '+permission_name+' ON ASSEMBLY::['+ sa.name +'] to
['+user_name(dp.grantee_principal_id)+'] ;' from 
sys.database_permissions dp  inner join  sys.certificates sa on 
sa.certificate_id   = dp.major_id
```

Comment: i am getting collation cannot reslove error

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT` in the JOINS.

```
SELECT 'GRANT '+permission_name+' ON ASSEMBLY::['+ sa.name +'] to ['+user_name(dp.grantee_principal_id)+'] ;'
FROM sys.database_permissions dp
INNER JOIN sys.certificates sa ON sa.certificate_id COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = dp.major_id COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work.

```
select 'GRANT '+permission_name+' ON ASSEMBLY::['+ sa.name +'] to
['+user_name(dp.grantee_principal_id)+'] ;'
from sys.database_permissions dp  inner join  sys.certificates sa on 
sa.certificate_id COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = dp.major_id COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

Comment: Wrongly placed collate clause at the end.